# Xcode linker error with exit code 1

Tags: swift, xcode

```
ld: entry point (_main) undefined. 
for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have done the following:

> -> Open .xcworkspace
>   -> updated pods
>   -> checked for any multiple paths
>   -> other linker flags in build settings
>   -> removed files from simulator's derived data

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to clear the project, and close `Xcode` and its `simulator`

Comment: already tried that

Comment: you not set entry point of view controller or check info.plist you need to set Storyboard name

Comment: @VishalPatel : both are done

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the error by adding :

@UIApplicationMain to the AppDelegate file